# PDE $u_t+u^2u_x=0$ how do we deduce/know that the second shock line starts at the $(x=3,t=3)$ point

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I am analyzing solution the below PDE. This is the example 1.14 from the textbook (p.19 http://people.uncw.edu/hermanr/pde1/PDEbook/PDE_Main.pdf)

My question 
**how do we deduce/know that the second shock line starts at the point  $(x=3,t=3)$?**

$$u_t+u^2u_x=0, \ \ |x|< \infty , \ \ t>0 $$

with boundary condition 
$$u(x,0)= \left\{\begin{matrix}
0 &   x\leq 0,  \\ 
1 & 0<x<2,  \\ 
0 & x \geq 2
\end{matrix}\right.$$

There is a picture of the characteristic lines 
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first shock occurs at $(2,0)$ and propogates with a slope ($\frac{\Delta t}{\Delta x}$) of 3 (found from Rankine Hugoniot conditions). The next shock will occur when the bottom of the rarefaction hits this line. The bottom of the rarefaction is the line $t=x$ and the initial shock line is $t=3x-6$; these intersect at $x=3=t$.